# Android return two items but only show one

Tags: android, listview, return, items

I got a little problem with my code.

I want to fetch two values within the for loop but only show one.

Here is my code

```
public class ReturnValue
{
    public String item;
    public String item_intro;
}



public ArrayList<ReturnValue> populate() {
    ArrayList<ReturnValue> returnValues = new ArrayList<ReturnValue>();

    while {
        ReturnValue rv = new ReturnValue();

    try {
        URL url = new URL
        ("http://www.wvvzondag2.nl/android/fillverslag.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
            (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        // gets the server json data
        BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String next;

        //While loop to go through the query until reached the end
        while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(next);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                String var = "";
                String var_intro = "";
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                var = jo.getString("title");
                var_intro = jo.getString("introtext");
                items_intro.add(var_intro);
                items.add(var);
                }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rv.item = var;
    rv.item_intro = var_intro;

    returnValues.add(rv);
}
return returnValues;
}
```

After some modification from tom now the main part of the code looks like this.

But I still got some errors

Syntax error on token "while", delete this token

items_intro cannot be resolved

items cannot be resolved

Don't know how to fix this...

With Kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: First, you can only return one object. If you want to return both arrrays, you have to create an object with both of them, but... Why do you have two vars (items and items_intro) that are equal and why do you want to return both?

Comment: @luanjot I suspect there's a typo in the inner loop, and he meant to do `items_intro.add(var_intro2)`.  So the two ArrayLists would be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can only return one object. One option is to create a "Wrapper object" containing your lists, and return that.

```
public class ReturnValue
{
    public String item;
    public String item_intro;
}
```

Then in your populate method:

```
public ArrayList<ReturnValue> populate() {
    ArrayList<ReturnValue> returnValues = new ArrayList<ReturnValue>();

    while {
        ReturnValue rv = new ReturnValue();
        //...
        //other code
        //...
        rv.item = var;
        rv.item_intro = var;

        returnValues.add(rv);
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply
I tried you´re way but it´s giving me a message..

Type mismatch: cannot convert from VerslagJSONParser.ReturnValue to ArrayList<String>

Comment: Oeps, my bad, I edited my code. The populate method should return ReturnValue instead of ArrayList<String>

Comment: Now I got a an error in the onCreate in my setListAdapter

The constructor ArrayAdapter(VerslagJSONParser, int, VerslagJSONParser.ReturnValue) is undefined

Comment: The thing is I do need that function, cause if I change/delete it then my list wont be filled

Comment: Ok, completely rewrote the code. I think I give you at least the way to go forward. I also suggest you to read about ListViews..

Comment: I changed the code but I think I´m doing it wrong?
Cause i'm still getting an error

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return two values. Return does not work that way. Return ends the method and returns one (1) value. For what you are doing, consider returning an array (or list) of lists or use a Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

YOu *could* create another ArrayList which contains objects items and items_into, then return this 2-element ArrayList.  You'd assume that items is the first element, and items_into is the 2nd element

Answer (score 0):

Methods can only return one value. Yet you could create two different methods, the one returning the one type and the other the other type. This way you can retrieve both values.